# How to extract files with date pattern using python

Tags: regex, python-2.7, date

I have n-files in a folder like

**source_dir**

```
 abc_2017-07-01.tar   
 abc_2017-07-02.tar 
 abc_2017-07-03.tar 
 pqr_2017-07-02.tar
```

Lets consider for a single pattern now 'abc'

(but I get this pattern randomly from Database, so need double filtering,one for pattern and one for last day)

And I want to extract file of last day ie '2017-07-02'

Here I can get common files but not exact last_day files

**Code**

```
pattern = 'abc'
allfiles=os.listdir(source_dir)
m_files=[f for f in allfiles if str(f).startswith(pattern)]
print m_files
```

**output:**

```
  [ 'abc_2017-07-01.tar' ,  'abc_2017-07-02.tar' , 'abc_2017-07-03.tar' ]
```

This gives me all files related to abc pattern, but how can filter out only last  day file of that pattern

**Expected :**

```
 [ 'abc_2017-07-02.tar' ]
```

Thanks

Comment: Whouldn't you expect `abc_2017-07-03.tar` ?

Comment: @MrGrj No I m looking for past day file. even file pattern may change randomly . so need to filter twice one for pattern and then for date

Comment: You could get the current date and look for that date - 1 day in you files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just a minor tweak in your code can get you the desired result.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

allfiles=os.listdir(source_dir)
file_date = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=-1)
pattern = 'abc_' +str(file_date.date())
m_files=[f for f in allfiles if str(f).startswith(pattern)]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
latest = max(m_files, key=lambda x: x[-14:-4])
```

will find the filename with latest date among filenames in `m_files`.

Answer (score 0):

use python regex package  like :

```
    import re 
    import os 

    files = os.listdir(source_dir)
    for file in files: 
            match = re.search('abc_2017-07-(\d{2})\.tar', file)
            day = match.group(1)
```

and then you can work with day in the loop to do what ever you want. Like create that list:

```
    import re 
    import os 

    def extract_day(name):
        match = re.search('abc_2017-07-(\d{2})\.tar', file)
        day = match.group(1)
        return day 


    files = os.listdir(source_dir)
    days = [extract_day(file) for file in files]
```

if the month is also variable you can substitute '*07*' with '*\d\d*' or also '*\d{2}*'. Be carefull if you have files that dont match with the pattern at all, then *match.group()* will cause an error since match is of type none.  Then use :

```
    def extract_day(name):
        match = re.search('abc_2017-07-(\d{2})\.tar', file)
        try:
            day = match.group(1) 
        except :
            day = None
        return day
```